# flutter search function which handle null

Tags: flutter, dart

I have written this code for search

```
  void Search(String _text) {
    if (_text.isEmpty) {
      BrandsList = RegisterBusiness().getBrands();
    } else {
      BrandsList = RegisterBusiness().getBrands().where((element) {
        return element.englishName.contains(_text);
      }).toList();
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

it works fine until there is a null "englishName" in my list and it completely destroys whole process.
what can I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should review [this](https://dart.dev/null-safety).

Answer (score 0):

try to a condition to verfy if englishName is not null

```
 void Search(String _text) {
            if (_text.isEmpty) {
              BrandsList = RegisterBusiness().getBrands();
            } else {
              BrandsList = RegisterBusiness().getBrands().where((element) {
                if (element.englishName != null) return element.englishName.contains(_text); // return if englishname is not null
                else return false ;
              }).toList();
            }
            setState(() {});
          }
        }
```

Comment: "This function has a return type of 'bool', but doesn't end with a return statement."  this is the error after using it.

Comment: @ardeshirojan sorry can you try again i edited the code